# Is it possible to add elements to an array previously defined as string

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, tokenize

I need to read a text file and store the text in the file in five different arrays. The text file contains questions, four options and the correct answer in one line. I used the scanner to read the textfile and store the whole text as a string and then was trying to use the string tokenizer to differentiate the questions and the options so i could store them in their respective errors. The compiler gives me error when i try doing this:

```
public void readFile()
{
    while (reader.hasNext())
    {
        String allText = reader.next();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(allText, ",");
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
        {
            question[index] = tokenizer.nextElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what **error** does the compiler give?

Comment: please give us an example, how the line is formatted

Comment: How does `question` defined?

Answer (score 0):

If `question` is a String, you can't add elements to it. You need to create a collection of Strings in order to add a String to it (you can use Array, List, Set etc.)